# K2961 Mosfet Equivalent

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I've been searching for a replacement for a Toshiba K2961 MOSFET for a few days, but I can't seem to find any.
The datasheet for it is available here:
http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/213272/TOSHIBA/2SK2961_06.html

Perhaps someone can help me find an equivalent model of MOSFET to replace it?
Thanks in advanced, any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in a rarely found Japanese extended TO-92-style through-hole package (probably an internal leadframe tab for higher power dissipation) and has relatively low input capacitance and relatively high Id/Idp.

Frankly, I think you'd be better searching for the exact part if you're not able to reverse engineer the circuit.

Look for a 2SK2961. The 2S is a Japanese thing - they leave it off. You can find replacement parts for a dollar or two.

Comment: I searched around and found one for 4$ shipped, not too bad. Thanks!